# Stanford NLP named entities of more than one token

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm experimenting with Stanford Core NLP for named entity recognition.

Some named entities consist of more than one token, for example, Person: "Bill Smith". I can't figure out what API calls to use to determine when "Bill" and "Smith" should be considered a single entity, and when they should be two different entities.

Is there some decent documentation somewhere which explains this?

Here's my current code:

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(MODEL_NAME);
    if (MODEL_NAME.endsWith(".gz")) {
        is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
    }
    is = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");

    AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(is);
    is.close();

    String text = "Hello, Bill Smith, how are you?";

    List<List<CoreLabel>> sentences = classifier.classify(text);
    for (List<CoreLabel> sentence: sentences) {
        for (CoreLabel word: sentence) {
            String type = word.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class);
            System.out.println(word + " is of type " + type);
        }
    }
```

Also, it isn't clear to me why the "PERSON" annotation is coming back as AnswerAnnotation, instead of CoreAnnotations.EntityClassAnnotation, EntityTypeAnnotation, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the "entitymentions" annotator, which will mark continuous sequences of tokens with the same ner tag as an entity.  The list of entities for each sentence will be stored under the  CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class key.  Each entity mention itself will be a CoreMap.

Looking over this code could help:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/EntityMentionsAnnotator.java

some sample code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;



public class EntityMentionsExample {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    String text = "Joe Smith is from Florida.";
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("text: " + text);
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      for (CoreMap entityMention : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.print(entityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));
        System.out.print("\t");
        System.out.print(
                entityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class));
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Three quick questions: How does this code know which models to load? This code is much slower to load than my original code; how to reduce startup time? Is there better documentation anywhere?

Comment: It is loading default models.  You can set what model to load with the property "ner.model".  In general I would stick with my code and use a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline.  The independent classifier is sort of an older way of using the ner stuff.  This is the documentation site: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Comment: Here is some more specific commentary on the API: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: If you want to use the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline but not have to constantly reload it, you could structure your code to simply make calls to a Stanford CoreNLP server.  Here is documentation about the server: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: But if you just want a simple Java class that starts up and runs there is no getting around loading the models at start up.